# Worksheet Codename Errors

Tags: vba, excel

When using the code below to reference a worksheet by codename, I get file explorer opening up for each instance of the "Sheet34". How can I prevent this?

```
Private Sub CheckBox4_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheetName As String


If CheckBox4.Value = True Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect
    Worksheets("SUMMARY").Unprotect
    sheetName = Sheets("Control").Cells(16, "I")
    If sheetName = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a valid Allowance descriptor. No entry was detected."
        CheckBox4.Value = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Len(sheetName) > 31 Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet tab names cannot be greater than 31 characters in length."
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets("Control").Cells(16, "I").ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        CheckBox4.Value = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim IllegalCharacter(1 To 7) As String, i As Integer
    IllegalCharacter(1) = "/"
    IllegalCharacter(2) = "\"
    IllegalCharacter(3) = "["
    IllegalCharacter(4) = "]"
    IllegalCharacter(5) = "*"
    IllegalCharacter(6) = "?"
    IllegalCharacter(7) = ":"
    For i = 1 To 7
        If InStr(sheetName, (IllegalCharacter(i))) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "You used a character that violates sheet naming rules. Please refrain from the following characters: / \ [ ] * ? : "
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Sheets("Control").Cells(16, "I").ClearContents
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            CheckBox4.Value = False
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Next i
    If Sheets("Control").Range("I16") = Sheets("Control").Range("I17") Then
        MsgBox "There is already an Allowance with this name. Please choose a different name."
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Sheets("Control").Cells(16, "I").ClearContents
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            CheckBox4.Value = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Sheets("Control").Range("I16") = Sheets("Control").Range("I18") Then
        MsgBox "There is already an Allowance with this name. Please choose a different name."
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Sheets("Control").Cells(16, "I").ClearContents
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            CheckBox4.Value = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Sheets("Control").Range("I16") = Sheets("Control").Range("I21") Then
        MsgBox "There is already an Other Item with this name. Please choose a different name."
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Sheets("Control").Cells(16, "I").ClearContents
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            CheckBox4.Value = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Sheets("Control").Range("I16") = Sheets("Control").Range("I22") Then
        MsgBox "There is already an Other Item with this name. Please choose a different name."
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Sheets("Control").Cells(16, "I").ClearContents
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            CheckBox4.Value = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Sheets("Control").Range("I16") = Sheets("Control").Range("I23") Then
        MsgBox "There is already an Other Item with this name. Please choose a different name."
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Sheets("Control").Cells(16, "I").ClearContents
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            CheckBox4.Value = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
    If WorksheetExists(sheetName) Then
        Worksheets(sheetName).Visible = -1
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Rows("47").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 2).Value = "ALL 1:"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 3).Value = "='Control'!I16"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 3).NumberFormat = "General"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 4).Value = "='Control'!K16"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 5).Value = "='Control'!L16"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 6).Value = "=" & sheetName & "!$H$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 7).Value = "=" & sheetName & "!$J$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 8).Value = "=" & sheetName & "!$N$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 9).Value = "=" & sheetName & "!$P$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 10).Value = "=SUM(F47:I47)/D47"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 11).Value = "=L47/F3"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 12).Value = "=" & sheetName & "!$U$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 13).Value = "=L47/$K$57"
        ActiveWorkbook.Protect
        Sheets(sheetName).Protect
        Sheets("SUMMARY").Protect
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheet34
        ws.Name = sheetName
        ws.Protect
        ws.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Rows("47").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 2).Value = "ALL 1:"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 3).Value = "='Control'!I16"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 3).NumberFormat = "General"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 4).Value = "='Control'!K16"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 5).Value = "='Control'!L16"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 6).Value = "=" & ws.Name & "!$H$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 7).Value = "=" & ws.Name & "!$J$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 8).Value = "=" & ws.Name & "!$N$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 9).Value = "=" & ws.Name & "!$P$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 10).Value = "=SUM(F47:I47)/D47"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 11).Value = "=L47/F3"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 12).Value = "=" & ws.Name & "!$U$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 13).Value = "=L47/$K$57"

        ActiveWorkbook.Protect
        Sheets(sheetName).Protect
        Sheets("SUMMARY").Protect
        Worksheets("Control").Activate

    End If

End If
If CheckBox4.Value = False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect
    Worksheets("SUMMARY").Unprotect
    sheetName = Sheets("Control").Cells(16, "I")

    If WorksheetExists(sheetName) Then
        Worksheets(sheetName).Visible = 2
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Rows("47").EntireRow.ClearContents
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Rows("47").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveWorkbook.Protect
        Sheets(sheetName).Protect
        Sheets("SUMMARY").Protect
    End If

   End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Follow up question: This code is taking an existing sheet and renaming it. The concern I have is if the user names the sheet in Cell I16, then renames it, and unchecks or checks the box, I get a row on the Summary Worksheet with poor references. Also, the code will not allow me to enter the code below

```
Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 6).Value = "=" & sheetName & "!$H$69"
```

as

```
Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 6).Value = "="' & sheetName & '"!$H$69"
```

as it turns the & sheetName & into a comment. How can I fix this so that the worksheet is properly referenced in the code? Do I need to keep with the codename worksheet?

My thoughts on how to stop the renaming issue was to protect the named cell so long as the checkbox value is positive, and allow the user to edit the cell if the checkbox value is false; maybe adding a line of code that checks if the cell is being changed and asking the user if they are sure this is the cell they want to modify, which would clear the data, but not the formatting, of the existing spreadsheet.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about file explorer opening up for each instance of the "Sheet34", but your assignment should have the single quotes inside the double quotes, i.e. `"='" & sheetName & "'!$H$69"`

Comment: Good to know about the double quotes.

So far as the File Explorer opening up; the file explorer to open an Excel file shows up 5 times, for each instance of the line

 "=" & sheetName & "!$U$69"

The only thing I can assume is that because of the orientation of single and double quotes, it assumes the sheet is in another workbook, perhaps? Though I was under the assumption that calling a sheet by its codename intrinsically assumed the sheet was in the active workbook unless otherwise stated?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the value of a cell to a formula...Try out the following:

1. Create a direct link to a cell in another sheet within the same workbook
2. Open another workbook.
3. Create a direct link to a cell in a sheet from the other workbook

You will find that the following would be correct use for a worksheet reference:

```
Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 6).Formula = "='" & sheetName & "'!$H$69"
```

And the below for a workbook reference:

```
Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(47, 6).Formula = "='[" & Worboookpath & "] & sheetName & "'!$H$69"
```